# Probability that the product of two numbers in $\{0,1,...,10^{n - 1}\}$ contains $2n - k$ digits, $k = 0,1,...$

Tags: probability, number-theory, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

How to find the probability that the product of two numbers in ${0,1,...,10^n - 1}$ contains $2n-k$ digits, $k = 0,1,...$? As I understand, the sum of all the combinations of two numbers is equal to $10^{2n}$. But I can't understand how to find the sum of all the positive combinations. I understand that the product of these numbers is in $10^{2n-k-1} \le x*y < 10^{2n-k}$. But it doesn't help me. Explain me please, how I can find the sum of all the positive combinations.

Answer (score 1):

This will give an approximate answer, which will be very close.  The region of interest is the square $[0,10^n-1] \times [0,10^n-1]$ in the $xy$ plane.  The numbers with $2n-k$ digits are the numbers from $10^{2n-k-1}$ to $10^{2n-k}-1$.  Instead of counting lattice points, we can view $x$ and $y$ as continuous variables and find the area that corresponds to this range of products.  This is where the approximation comes from.  It is the area between the two hyperbolas $xy=10^{2n-k-1}$ and $10^{2n-k}$.  Do the integral and you are done.

Added:  let us do an example with $n=7, k=4$ so we are looking for factors less than or equal to $10^6$ that multiply to an eight digit number.  Such numbers are in the range $[10^7,10^8)$  Our square is $10^6 \times 10^6$ for a total area of $10^{12}$.  The lower boundary of the area we are looking at is $xy=10^7$ and the upper boundary is $xy=10^8$.  The lower hyperbola hits the edges of the square at $(10,10^6)$ and $(10^6,10)$.  The area below it and inside the square is $$10 \cdot 10^6+\int_{10}^{10^6}\frac {10^7}x\ dx=10^7+10^7 \log(10^5) \approx 1.2513\cdot 10^8$$
where the first term is the rectangle to the left of the intersection with the top of the square.  Similarly the upper hyperbola hits the square at $(100,10^6)$ and $(10^6,100)$ so the area below it is
$$100 \cdot 10^6+\int_{100}^{10^6}\frac {10^8}x\ dx=10^8+10^8 \log(10^4) \approx 10.2103\cdot 10^8$$
The difference of areas is then $8.959 \cdot 10^8$  That is approximately the number of pairs that have a product with eight digits.

Comment: As I understand, we need to draw two graphs: $xy = 10^{2n-k-1}$ and $xy = 10^{2n-k}$. But then why do we need the square. How it can help us, if we can just draw two hyperbolas, integrate a zone between them and get a solution? And why can we get an approximate answer but not the accurate answer, if integral gives as accurate answer?

Comment: The correct answer is all the lattice points that are between those two curves, counting those on the bottom one and not on the top.  When we calculate the area we spread the lattice point over the square.  The squares that cross the lower boundary contribute area but no lattice points.  The squares that cross the upper boundary contribute lattice points but less than $1$ in area.  That is the approximation.

Comment: But how this integral can help us? I took an integral and answer is $ln{10}$. But how can it help us? Because I thought that this integral gives us all the positive combinations, but $ln{10}$ is very little. How this integral helps us to find all the positive combinations?

Comment: You didn't do the integral correctly.  The area of the square is $10^{2n-2}$.  That is split into $2n$ pieces, one for each $k$, so some of them are rather large.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain one more time please about this integral and how it is connected to the square? As I understand, my integral is incorrect because $10^{2n-k}$ is supremum but not the maximum, right?

Comment: Sorry for stupid questions but I am very weak in geometric probabilities.

Comment: Each $x,y$ pair is represented by a lattice point in the square.  The hyperbolas $xy=10^m$ cut the square into pieces where each piece has the same number of digits.  The answer to your question is the number of lattice points in each piece.  There is one lattice point per square unit of area.  The integration allows us to compute the area, which is an approximation to the number of lattice points.  You didn't show what you did for an integral, so I don't know what is wrong.  It isn't the difference between sup and max.

Answer (score 0):

I would express the probability in terms of logarithms, base $(10)$.

The positive integer $n$ will have exactly $k$ digits if and only if 
$10^{k-1} \leq n < 10^k \implies (k-1) \leq \log_{10} n < k.$

Further, $\log_{10}(ab) = \log_{10}a + \log_{10}b.$

---

For a given fixed $n$ and fixed $k$, let $r$ denote $(2n-k).$ 
Let $S$ denote the set $\{1,2,\cdots, 10^{n} -1\}.$ 
Notice that I have **necessarily** exluded the element $0$ from the set $S$,
because (among other things) $\log_{10} (0)$ is **undefined**.

It shouldn't be too onerous to modify the discussion below to include consideration
of what happens if the set $S$ is appended with the element $(0)$, and
one or both of the numbers chosen is $(0)$.

There are exactly $D = (10^n -1)^2$ ways of selecting two numbers at random from
the set $S$ such that the selection is done **with replacement**.

Thus, when attempting to compute a probability, $D$ will represent the denominator. 
Therefore, the problem is reduced to computing the numerator $N$, for a specific value of
$r$.

**Edit**
Thanks to prostak for indicating that my original computation of $N$ (below) was flawed.
Answer has been edited.

Given any element $s \in S$:

Let $f(s)$ to denote the smallest positive integer $a$ such that 
$\log_{10}s + \log_{10}a \geq (r-1).$

Let $g(s)$ to denote the largest positive integer $b$ such that 
$\log_{10}s + \log_{10}b < (r).$ 
Note that $g(s)$ is **undefined**, for $s \geq 10^r.$

Note:
To facilitate the summation formula at the end of this answer, I am going to employ
the following contrivance:

For $s < (10)^r,$ let $h(s)$ denote $g(s) - f(s) + 1.$ 
For $s \geq (10)^r,$ let $h(s)$ denote $0$.

Then $$N = \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} h(i) = \sum_{i=1}^{10^r - 1} h(i).$$

**Edit**
While preparing my Addendum-2 response to prostak's comment/question, I realized that the expression above is wrong.  It overlooks that 
$r = (2n - k)$ might be larger than $n$.
In such a circumstance, given the fact that $s$ is required to be $\leq (10^n - 1),$ it would not make any sense to have the summation exceed $(10^n - 1).$
Therefore, the corrected expression is:

$$N = \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} h(i).$$

Since the artificial contrivance that
$i \geq 10^r \implies h(i) = 0$ is being used,
the situations where $r = (2n - k) < n$ continue to be handled okay.

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment/question of prostak

> As I understand

> $$N ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} \frac{\left(10^{2n-k} - 10^{2n-k-1}\right)}{i} ~+~ 1.$$

> But how can we get this sum if this row is divergent?

First of all, my expression for $N$ is

$$N ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} h(i) = \sum_{i=1}^{10^r - 1} h(i)\tag1$$

My expression is intended to represent the exact number of ordered pairs 
$(a,b)$ such that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, $a,b$ are each less than $(10^n)$, 
and the product $(a \times b)$ has exactly $r = (2n - k)$ digits.

The idea is that there are exactly $D = (10^n - 1)^2$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ 
that one might choose at random, where each component of the ordered pair is in 
$\{1,2,\cdots, (10^n - 1)\}$.
Therefore, the chance of a
a *satisfying* ordered pair occurring, at random, is $\frac{N}{D}.$

If I understand your comment/question correctly, you are comparing the
expression in equation (1) above to the following expression:

$$N ~=~ \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} 
\frac{\left(10^{2n-k} - 10^{2n-k-1}\right)}{i} ~+~ 1.\tag2$$

You are then indicating that the expression in equation (2) above is
"divergent".

I will be happy to respond by adding a second (**Addendum-2**) section to
my answer.  But first, I need you to **edit your original query**, adding your own
**Addendum**, that does the following:

- Demonstrate, in very clear detail, how you derived equation (2) above, from
  equation (1) above.
- My description of $N$ is that it is the number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $(a \times b)$ has exactly $r = (2n - k)$ digits.
  I need you to explain in English, whether you are also using the variable $N$
  to signify the same thing.  If not, I need you to explain what you are
  intending that the variable $N$ should signify.
- You have also indicated that the expression in equation (2) above is
  "divergent".  That expression refers to a finite number of terms,
  each of which is well defined (and therefore finite).  Therefore, I am
  confused by what you intend by the description "divergent".  Please
  explain further, again providing very clear mathematical detail.

Given the questions that I am posing, I feel that it is not appropriate for you to attempt to provide the requested details in
one or more comments.  Instead, please edit your query to provide the details.

---

**Addendum-2**
Responding to the comment/question of prostak:

Nice detail provided as you were following up your question.  One minor point: 
The comments don't really lend themselves to complicated math discussions, although
you've obviously mastered using MathJax nicely.  It is better to edit your query,
as I edit mine, for this type of back and forth.

Chat room is another alternative, but it is somewhat difficult because we have
conflicting schedules and because I (for one) haven't found a way to render
math nicely in the chat room.  So, if we need to continue going back and forth,
let's do it 
using query <--> answer (i.e. you edit your query and I will edit my answer), and simply leave short flagging comments, to
notify each other.

$\underline{\text{Your comment/question}}$

You indicated that:

$$\text{if} ~s = 2, f(s) \geq \frac{10^{2n-k-1}}{2}~ \text{and} ~g(s) < \frac{10^{2n-k}}{2}.\tag3$$

$$\text{if} ~s = 3, f(s) \geq \frac{10^{2n-k-1}}{3}~ \text{and} ~g(s) < \frac{10^{2n-k}}{3}.\tag4$$

You then concluded that

$$\text{if} ~s = 10^n - 1, f(s) \geq 
\frac{10^{2n - k - 1}}{10^n - 1}~ \text{and} 
~g(s) < \frac{10^{2n-k}}{10^n - 1}.\tag5$$

You then inferred that

$$h(i) = \frac{10^{2n-k} - 10^{2n-k-1}}{i} + 1\tag6$$

and that we need to sum $h(i)$ in $[1,10^n - 1]$ which is a problem, because
this sum hasn't a well defined evaluation.

---

$\underline{\text{My Responses}}$

Best to take these points one at a time.

First, notice the correction that I made in the specification of $N$, just before the (first) Addendum.

For any real number $r$, let $\lfloor r\rfloor$ denote the largest
integer $\leq r$ (i.e. the floor of $r$).

For any real number $r$, let $\lceil r\rceil$ denote the smallest
integer $\geq r$ (i.e. the ceiling of $r$).

Assuming that $n,k$ fixed, with $r = (2n-k)$, then, for any positive integer $s$, 
my definition of $f(s)$ is that it is the smallest positive integer $a$ such that
$\log_{10} s + \log_{10} a \geq (2n - k - 1)$.

From this definition, you know that $s \times a \geq 10^{2n - k - 1}.$ 
This implies that $a \geq \frac{10^{2n - k - 1}}{s}$.
Since $a$ is required to be a positive integer, my definition of $f(s)$ may be
equivalently expressed as

$$f(s) = \left\lceil \frac{10^{2n - k - 1}}{s}\right\rceil$$

Similarly, my definition of $g(s)$ is that 
**if** $~s \geq 10^{2n - k},~$ **then** $~g(s)~$ is **undefined**. 
**Otherwise** $g(s)$ is the largest positive integer $b$ such that
$\log_{10} s + \log_{10} b < (2n - k)$.

From this definition, you know that when $s < 10^{2n - k},$
and $b$ is as specified above 
then $s \times b < 10^{2n - k}$, which implies that
$b < \frac{10^{2n-k}}{s}.$ 
Since $b$ is required to be a positive integer, my definition of $g(s)$ may be
equivalently expressed as

$$ s \geq 10^{2n-k} \implies g(s) ~~\text{is undefined.  Otherwise}~~
g(s) = \left\lfloor \frac{10^{2n - k} - 1}{s}\right\rfloor.$$

The inequalities expressed in equations (3) and (4) are accurate, though (perhaps) misleading, since they don't focus on the fact that both $f(s)$ and $g(s)$ are required to be positive integers.

With respect to equation (5) above, I would also point out that $g(s)$ is undefined when $s \geq 10^{2n - k}.$  Therefore, since equation (5) is specifically focusing on $(s = 10^n - 1)$, the specification of $g(s)$ in equation (5) is incorrect, in those cases where $(2n - k) < (n).$

Finally, your specification for $h(i)$ in equation (6) is wrong and should be:

$$\text{When} ~~i \geq 10^{2n -k}, ~h(i) = 0.$$

$$\text{Otherwise} ~~h(i) ~=~
\left\lfloor \frac{10^{2n - k} - 1}{i}\right\rfloor ~-~
\left\lceil \frac{10^{2n - k - 1}}{i}\right\rceil ~+1.$$

This should resolve your inference that for some values of $i, ~h(i)$ can't be evaluated.  If you have further questions, please edit your query and then leave me another flagging comment.

Comment: As I understand $$N = \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} \frac{(10^{2n-k}-10^{2n-k-1})} {i} + 1$$. But how can we get this sum if this row is divergent?

Comment: @prostak I have added an Addendum to my answer for you to review, and, if you wish, respond to.

Comment: Ok.In (1) you write: $$N = \sum_{i=1}^{10^n - 1} h(i)$$ I wanted to define $h(i) = g(s) - f(s) + 1$. if s = 2, $f(s) \geq \frac{10^{2n-k-1}} {2}$ and $g(s) < \frac{10^{2n-k}} {2}$. if s = 3, $f(s) \geq \frac{10^{2n-k-1}} {3}$ and $g(s) < \frac{10^{2n-k}} {3}$ etc. Then, if s = $10^{n} - 1$, $f(s) \geq \frac{10^{2n-k-1}} {10^{n} - 1}$ and $g(s) < \frac{10^{2n-k}} {10^{n} - 1}$. That is why $$h(i) = \frac{\left(10^{2n-k} - 10^{2n-k-1}\right)}{i} ~+~ 1.$$ Then we need to sum it for i in range $[1, 10^{n} - 1]$. But this sum hasn't defined answer. That is what I am talking about.

Comment: @prostak See the Addendum-2 that I just added to my answer.